# Why do I need uniform convergence?

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

This is from baby Rudin problem 7.9:

Let $f_n$ be a sequence of continuous functions which converges uniformly to a function $f$ on a set $E$. Prove that:

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} f_n(x_n)= f(x)$$

for every sequence of points $x_n \in E$ such that $x_n \rightarrow x$ for $x \in E$.

**What I've tried**

We want to show:

$$|f_n(x_n) - f(x)| \rightarrow 0$$

By the hypothesis on $x_n$:

$$|f_n(x_n) - f(x)| = \left|f_n\left(x + o(1)\right) - f(x)\right| = \left| f_n\left(x \right) + o(1) - f(x) \right|$$

Where the second equality comes from the continuity of $f_n$. This clearly goes to $0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$. Nowhere have I used the uniform convergence of $f_n$ to $f$. What did I miss?

I have seen [Why do I need uniform convergence here?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1492742/why-do-i-need-uniform-convergence-here) but my argument is different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not  a huge fan of the $o(1)$ notation being used here, and this may be hiding where the mistake lies. It is true that for any fixed $n$ you have $f_{n}(x + o(1)) = f_{n}(x) + o(1)$ (using your notation). However, this may not be true for all $n$ sufficiently large. In fact, saying that it is true for all $n$ sufficiently large is virtually the definition of uniform convergence! Without uniform convergence, what can happen is that as $n$ gets larger, the $o(1)$ quantity converges more and more slowly to zero, and in the limit may no longer converge to zero at all!

Comment: That intuition makes a lot of sense, thanks. Looking closer at the question linked about it's clear that I'm making the same mistake as the OP there: the indices of $x_n$ and $f_n$ are equal, so I cannot take $x_n$ arbitrarily close to $x$ independent of taking $f_n$ to $f$. Here is where the uniform convergence is applied.

Comment: That's another good way of phrasing it!